# Ubuntu 19.10 Updates Fail

Tags: update-manager

Whenever my system tries to update itself after upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10, it fails. I'm not sure what or where the problem is so what should I do to get it to update?

[image: Screen capture of error message.]

Running *sudo apt-get update && sudo do-release-upgrade* gives several lines of output including this error:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked.
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo do-release-upgrade`, you'll get plenty of useful output— copy them here if there's any error.

Comment: @Jim Thank you, error output posted!

Comment: So what does _Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked._ mean and how do I get rid of it? I'm getting it on two of my systems after upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try unmasking this unit like this:

```
sudo systemctl unmask mount
```

Comment: Thank you. On one system, it gives ***Unit mount.service does not exist, proceeding anyway*** but the other system is unavailable right now so I'll give it a try there once it is back online after a remodel.